# Proper format for NSPredicate

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create an `NSPredicate` for a Core Data `NSFetchRequest`. The attribute `toBeDeleted` is an `NSNumber`. Do I need to insert `boolValue` in the format string?

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "toBeDeleted.boolValue == true")
```

Comment: So. Did you try reading the docs on how to [make an NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html) or on how a predicate [format string](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795) must be constructed? Did you try _running_ the code you wrote?

Comment: Yes, I'm still reading and having a headache at the same time since I'm only a beginner.

Comment: Try without the `.boolValue`

Comment: thank you. @matt I did try running the code but didn't know even how to make sense of the results I was getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kevin and @matt have properly pointed out [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/index.html), the proper way to do it is without the `.boolValue`